# Differences between onClick and onSubmit in Google Analytics Event Tracking

Tags: google-analytics

I had a website where there was a link to a hotel booking engine and had been using onSubmit to record a form submission as an event.

However it didn't seem to be recording properly - the figures were too low.

So, I thought that maybe changing to onClick would help - so the code on the form would look like this:

```
<form id="bookingEngine" 
      class="bookingEngine" 
      name="bookingEngine" 
      action="redirect.php" 
      method=POST 
      target="_blank" 
     onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'Booking', 'Website');
     ">
```

This works, except now the figures are much higherand look as if maybe overreporting?

Is this right, could the onClick on a form tag be recording something other than the number of forms submitted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more simplistic explanation would be that the onclick tracks when an element is clicked, regardless of the outcome or the context in which the element was clicked, whereas the onbusmit tracks when a form button is clicked and the form successfully submitted. So if there were errors in the form that invalidated the form, and it doesn't get submitted, then the onsubmit action would not occur.